# How to deploy different react web apps through one express server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, webserver

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to deploy an express server that serves different apps on different routes. (Not a front end and and api.) So, for instance let's say I wanted to run a "Hello World." app through a finite number of routes (like a home/landing page) and then deploy a "My app" app through a certain URL route with each react app using react router. Is this possible? If so, how can it be done?

Comment: would be nice if you could share some code you have tried and the issue/s you're facing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U should provide `homepage` in `package.json` for each react-app,
for example

---

```
__
 |_ app1/
 |_ app2/
 |_ server/
```

for app1 package.json `homepage: "/app1"`

for app2 package.json `homepage: "/app2"`

Express server code:

```
app.use("/app1", express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "../app1/build")))
app.use("/app2", express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "../app2/build")))

app.get("/app1", (_req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "../app1/build/index.html"))
})

app.get("/app2", (_req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "../app2/build/index.html"))
})
```

I hope I was able to help

### Edit:

Also you can provide `basename` prop for `BrowserRouter` or `HashRouter`

For app1 `basename="app1"` and for app2 `basename="app2"`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this doesn't appear to work. Just getting blank white screens returned.

Comment: check urls for static react files

Comment: Okay, this method seems not to load the assets correctly. When I define one of the apps to the base route "/" it works for that app, but won't load the assests when defined as /app1 route.

So if I change say the first argument "/app1" in the use/get functions to "/" the assets load correctly for that app. Same if I change "/app2" to "/", but they won't load as defined currently.

Comment: So I will accept this answer if you change the `app.use("/app1"...)` and `app.use("/app2"...)` to `app.use("/"...)`. It'd also be cool if I could figure out why I seem to have to do that. Any ideas?

Comment: if you provide `homepage` in `package.json`, in `index.html` path will change from `/static/js/2.e23c04ee.chunk.js` ti `/app1/static/js/2.e23c04ee.chunk.js`

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks!